# DNS Query.log - Multiple query’s for ripe.net

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind

Currently I run a DNS server (bind9) that handles queries from clients over the internet lately I have noticed hundreds of queries from all different address's that look like this (Server IP removed)

```
client 216.59.33.210#53: query: ripe.net IN ANY +ED (0.0.0.0)
client 216.59.33.204#53: query: ripe.net IN ANY +ED (0.0.0.0)
client 208.64.127.5#53: query: ripe.net IN ANY +ED (0.0.0.0)
client 184.107.255.202#53: query: ripe.net IN ANY +ED (0.0.0.0)
client 208.64.127.5#53: query: ripe.net IN ANY +ED (0.0.0.0)
client 208.64.127.5#53: query: ripe.net IN ANY +ED (0.0.0.0)
client 205.204.65.83#53: query: ripe.net IN ANY +ED (0.0.0.0)
client 69.162.110.106#53: query: ripe.net IN ANY +ED (0.0.0.0)
client 216.59.33.210#53: query: ripe.net IN ANY +ED (0.0.0.0)
client 69.162.110.106#53: query: ripe.net IN ANY +ED (0.0.0.0)
client 216.59.33.204#53: query: ripe.net IN ANY +ED (0.0.0.0)
client 208.64.127.5#53: query: ripe.net IN ANY +ED (0.0.0.0)
```

Can someone please explain why there are so many clients querying for ripe.net ?

Comment: I wrote a little bash script to automatic block the abusing ip addresses by checking the query.log
[Block ripe.net requests](http://pastebin.com/q68apaZn)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a DNS-server is configured openly like this it is abused by others in DNS amplifications attacks. The attacker forges the IP-addresses of the DDOS targets and send out a lot of small queries (often of type ANY) to servers like yours.

ripe.net ANY is used because it returns a large answer and therefore amplifies the size of the attackers spoofed query towards the target.

Comment: Thanks I have never heard of DNS amplifications attacks.. I will have a read now.

Comment: http://isotf.org/news/DNS-Amplification-Attacks.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Looks like what you want is to disable recursion or allow recursion to specific IP addresses (e.g. local host):

http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/queries.html#allow-recursion

The default is to allow anyone.